# running selenium headless using jenkins in windows

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

my application is made only for internet explorer. hence it does not work in phantom js or html unit driver. is it possible to run in Jenkins in headless mode in windows

Comment: IMO, it's very much possible & feasible.

Comment: can you explain more rather than yes/no

Comment: Can you show us your work/research?

Comment: your question is unclear and confusing?

Comment: @  Gaurang Shah kindly dont spam my question if you are unable to uderstand english

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can see the project below :-

https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/tree/master/headless_ie_selenium

OR

You can use triflejs.A headless Internet Explorer browser using the .NET WebBrowser Class with a Javascript API running on the V8 engine.

http://triflejs.org/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: this is not the answer for my question

Comment: Oh you want to run Jenkins in headless mode .. you can install Jenkins as a service with Jenkins exe file .. now Jenkins will be triggered by window service ... Hope it will help you